# Spring Data JPA with hibernate annotations

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

We have a large code base using Hibernate and JPA with hand-made DAO Layer. Entites are mapped with JPA annotations (javax.persistence) and if needed, hibernate-specific annotations (org.hibernate.annotations). We are at least using the following hibernate-specific annotations:

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.Immutable;
import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollection;
import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollectionOption;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
```

We want to move to Spring Data JPA for the DAO Layer. Can we use Spring Data JPA for entites annotated with JPA and Hibernate annotations?

Spring Data JPA comes with its own annotations, and it's unclear to me what we can mix or not.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data JPA is built on top of the JPA API which mainly allows you to abstract away from using JPA 's `EntityManager` directly and provide a declarative way to define the JPQL/native SQL to query the entities. In the end , it will use `EntityManager` to manage the entities under the cover.

So your question is just equivalent to asking can we use JPA 's `EntityManager` to manage the entity that are annotated with the hibernate specific annotations . The answer is yes and it is very normal to do so if you want to use some hibernate specific feature that is not defined in the JPA specification.

So I don't see any problems that you cannot do it.

This [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-lazycollection) is one of the example. It shows that we can use the `EntityManager` API to work with an entity that is annotated with `@LazyCollection`.

Comment: Spring Data JPA has its own annotations. How are they processed? How does Hibernate become aware of an annotations like org.springframework.data.annotation.Id ?

Comment: Hibernate will not know the existence of the spring-data .So it does not aware the spring data annotation. It is done in the other round , which when you use spring-data repository to process a hibernate entity , those spring-data annotation just provide more information to  spring-data repository to decide how to process the hibernate entity. Does it make sense to you ?

Comment: Do you mean that the spring-data mapping annotations are ignored by hibernate? I couldn’t find an official reference for this point.

Comment: Yes. Because from hibernate 's point of view , it does not know and care what is spring-data , so it is very normal that they will not mention spring-data in their documentation.... They are separate project. hibernate does not depend on spring-data , why they need to mention spring-data?  If you do not believe , go to Hibernate GitHub and search their source code , and look for their `pom.xml` etc, and you will find that it does not have any source codes that depend on spring-data

Comment: I meant that I didn’t find any statement in the spring-data docs that spring-data mapping annotations are ignored when using JPA. It’s clear that hibernate doesn’t depend on spring-data. But spring-data does lots of magic, like exception translation. It could also translate spring-data mapping annotations to JPA annotations, when loading the classes.

Comment: so you expect that spring-data documentation should mention hibernate will ignore the spring-data mapping annotations  ? I will not surprise if spring-data docs does not have a statement that explicitly mention this as it is a rather common sense to me that hibernate will ignore it. If you think they should improve spring-data doc to mention this explicitly , feel free to create a PR to them.

Answer (score 0):

Spring also uses the annotations from JPA to process into Hibernate, no change would be necessary